# convert object list to type array and remove null values

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get some data and convert it to a list of objects. From this list I want to select items that are not null and have a specific type. After that I want to convert these object variables to their correct type and return this list as an array.

```
        ContactEndpoint[] points = (GetContactInformation(contact, ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints) as List<object>)
            .Select(item => item)
            .Where(item => item != null && item is ContactEndpoint)
            .ConvertAll(item => item as ContactEndpoint)
            .ToArray();
```

using this code throws an error at `ConvertAll`

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ConvertAll'
>   and no extension method 'ConvertAll' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

My syntax seems to be wrong, all I want to do is

- get this data (returned as a List of objects)
- select all non null values and objects of type ContactEndpoint
- return it as an array

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Cast` or - since you want to filter - `Enumerable.OfType`:

So instead of

```
.Where(item => item != null && item is ContactEndpoint)
.ConvertAll(item => item as ContactEndpoint)
```

this (since `null` values never match any type they are filtered out implicitly by `OfType`):

```
.OfType<ContactEndpoint>()
```

`ConvertAll` is a method of `Arrray` or `List<T>`

Comment: @MHComputech: yes, since null values never match any type they are filtered out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ContactEndpoint[] points = (GetContactInformation(contact, ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints) as List<object>)
            .Where(item => item is ContactEndpoint)
            .Cast<ContactEndpoint>()
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: I think using `.OfType<ContactEndpoint>()` is the better solution but I upvoted yours too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    ContactEndpoint[] points = GetContactInformation(contact, 
                    ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints) 
        .Where(item => item != null)
        .OfType<ContactEndpoint>()
        .ToArray();
```

You should not need the `as List<object>`  or the `.Select(item => item)`

Comment: You do not need the Where since the OfType already sorts out null values.

Comment: I know, I saw Tims answer. I probably would leave it in in Production. Just for readability, don't leave questions for the reader.