# Convert List< Guid ?> to List< Guid >

Tags: c#, list, linq, casting

how convert List < Guid? > to List < Guid >

```
List<Guid?>  => List<Guid>
```

Comment: `.Select(x => x.Value)`, beware this will throw if any guid is null

Comment: `guids.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();` Btw, did you try something?

Comment: This is a narrowing conversion. Why is you source list `Guid?`? Perhaps you need to go upstream and see if you can fix the problem there?

Comment: More strictly `guids.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value).ToList()`. But fix the source. Don't do this hack.

Comment: Or `.Cast<Guid>()`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - That fails on `null`. You need `OfType<Guid>()` to filter.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, it was an alternative to `.Select(x => x.Value)`. It's not clear what behaviour is required with null

Comment: `var guidList = guids.Where(x => x != null).Cast<Guid>().ToList();`

Comment: related :  [convert object list to type array and remove null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096041/convert-object-list-to-type-array-and-remove-null-values/52096098), [Implicit convert `List<int?>` to `List<int>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394016/implicit-convert-listint-to-listint)

Comment: Could be better closed as duplicate of [Implicit convert `List<int?>` to `List<int>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394016/implicit-convert-listint-to-listint), if any gold badge wanna swing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine `Where` and `Select` from `System.Linq` methods for that

```cs
var result = guids.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: This is a bit of a hack though. The OP is better off fixing the source query that's building the data in the first place.

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree with you, but OP didn't mention anything here